# Date Matching lines without a date

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

Ok, I have a big log file that I filter buy date.

```
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me i got to much to say
so I continue on the next line of the file
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:11-Nov-2013 15:00:02 I am fine
ps6100-01:SP:11-Nov-2013 15:00:02 I am fine
```

I am using this to pull the current years events

```
CurYear=`date | awk '{ print $6 }'` 
perl -ne "print if /-$CurYear/" $file
```

The lines that have no date no not get pulled at all. So if run my statement, I want this.

```
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me i got to much to say
so I continue on the next line of the file
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
```

But I get this and some times its several lines so I am missing some critical things in my output.

```
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me i got to much to say
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
```

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- lines containing the year are always of the format:

> xxxxxx:xx:DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS ....

Sample input data:

```
$ cat logfile
ps6100-01:SP:11-Nov-2015 15:00:02 I am fine
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me i got to much to say
        so I continue on the next line of the file
and then another line
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:11-Nov-2013 15:00:02 I am fine
ps6100-01:SP:11-Nov-2013 15:00:02 I am fine
```

One `awk` idea:

```
CurYear=2014

awk -F':' -v cyear="${CurYear}" '                  # define input field separator as ":", pass in bash variable CurYear
NF>=5    { n=split($3,arr,"[-| ]")                 # split 3rd field on "-" and "<space>"
           printme = ( arr[3] == cyear ) ? 1 : 0   # if log file entry == CurYear then set printme flag else clear
         }
printme                                            # if printme flag == 1 then print current line
' logfile
```

This generates:

```
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me i got to much to say
        so I continue on the next line of the file
and then another line
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
ps6100-01:SP:12-Nov-2014 15:00:02 I am broken help me
```

Comment: Can i append any line that doent have my date to the line above it ?

Comment: not sure I understand the question; if this code does not do what you want then please update the question with a more representative set of data that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 1):

you can use perl for this

this assumes that ps6100 is common to all lines that have the date, you may need to change it to some other regex if it is not common to all lines

```
perl -ne 'chomp; /$ENV{"CurYear"}/ && do {print "\n$_"; $x=4}; --$x > 0 && $_ !~ /ps6100/ && print' file.log
```